# How to show an alert inside async method asp net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I want to display an alert when the async method is complete.

This is what I have so far:

```
private async void SetPassword()
{
    var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("RDSupport");

    string userId = Support.Instance.GetUserIDDatabase(_currentUser);

    UserStore<IdentityUser> userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
    UserManager<IdentityUser> manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
    IdentityUser user = manager.FindById(userId);

    manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<IdentityUser, string>
        (provider.Create("UserToken")) as IUserTokenProvider<IdentityUser, string>;

    string token = manager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(userId);

    manager.ResetPassword(userId, token, _newPassword);

    string hashedNewPassword = manager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(_newPassword);                

    await userStore.SetPasswordHashAsync(user, hashedNewPassword);
    await userStore.UpdateAsync(user);

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Password changed successfully!');", true);

    _success = true;
}
```

But ScriptManager isn't showing any message. Any ideas?

Comment: If you call an `async void` function it will be executed asynchronously without waiting to it's finish, so the problem is this code will be executed after the page has been rendered. change it to `async Task` and `await` it or make it synchronous.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to stick an UpdatePanel on your webpage, containing a label which your method could then write to.

Comment: @Gusman: That is generally true, but ASP.NET Web Pages does some extra work to asynchronously wait for `async void` methods to complete before sending the response.

Comment: @Gusman: Ok. Done. But now userStore.UpdateAsync(user) is taking too much time and it doesn't work.

Comment: @StephenCleary I know that ASP .net will track the async tasks to not send the response until it has finished, but does that implies it will not render the page until all the void tasks are finished? never read about it...

Comment: @Gusman: On ASP.NET, *only* Web Forms has the special `async void` behavior. Using `async void` with MVC/WebAPI can cause an `InvalidOperationException`. More info in my [article on `async` ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx), and - if you're interested in *how* WebForms does this - my [article on `SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).

Comment: @StephenCleary nice posts, very good info :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I describe on my blog, [`async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html). Once your server sends a response to a request, it can't later decide to send *another* response; HTTP just doesn't work that way.

I recommend that your JavaScript call this method via AJAX, and then just raise the alert itself when its AJAX `Promise` resolves.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever async and await you write, C# will execute fully on the server and not send intermediate JavaScript to the browser. `RegisterClientScriptBlock` is not used to send and execute JavaScript "inside" C# code